# How to automatically add type validation decorators to Nestjs dto

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I have a Nestjs application with hundreds of dtos, that look something like this:

```
export class ExampleDto {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  data: MyType;
...
}
```

I want to have the 'whitelist + forbidNonWhitelisted' behavior for input validation - meaning, I want to get a 400-bad request exception whenever I receive input that doesn't match the dto.

To achieve that using Nest's validation pipes I have to have a validation decorator for each property.
but adding `@IsString()` or `@IsNumber()` everywhere seems way too verbose, considering that information is already listed as the type.

Is there a setting I can use so that Nestjs validates the input based on the given type?

Alternatively- is there a script to automatically add those decorators?

Comment: Remember that types are stripped when transpiling to Javascript, so runtime validation based on them is not possible. Decorators are definitely the way to go here